# fix Arbitrary Location issue forever

Tags: git, version-control

How can I fix "Arbitrary Location" message/question **forever**?

... and what does trigger this message?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are talking about and Google doesn't seem to know either. Can you be more specific?

Comment: You must provide an example of the actual message and how you generated it. It looks like it comes from git-gui but that is not an error message - just a dialog field.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! People asking questions are generally expected to have done some prior research on what they are asking about. At the very least, the question should be a specific technical question with enough information about the context of the problem that people can work out an answer. You can find more information about this in our [FAQ].  (As you can tell from other comments, people who've used `git` have not always come across this issue, and are puzzled about how you run into it.)